# Error al tratar de insertar dinamicamente en listas de c# (No se puede agregar o insertar elementos en más de un sitio)

Tags: c#, listview

Bueno actualmente quiero llenar una listview con informacion de mi Base de Datos, pero me sale el siguiente error:

> Can not add or insert item in more than one site. You must first
>   remove it from its current location or clone it.

Codigo Actual:

```
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        lvi.Text = reader.GetString("Articulo");
        lvi.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("Costo"));
        lvi.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("Importancia"));
        lstData.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
    connection.Close();
```

El primer registro si lo ejecuta correctamente pero despues en el segundo es cuando me sale este error.

Codigo de la Lista:

```
        lstData.View = View.Details;

        lstData.Columns.Add("Nombre");
        lstData.Columns.Add("Precio");
        lstData.Columns.Add("Importancia");
        lstData.Columns[2].Width=110;
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de esta línea:

```
lstData.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Coloca:

```
lvi = new ListViewItem();
```

Tu código modificado quedaría así:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    lvi.Text = reader.GetString("Articulo");
    lvi.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("Costo"));
    lvi.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString("Importancia"));
    lstData.Items.Add(lvi);

    // Limpia la variable para poderla usar al iniciar el ciclo.
    lvi = new ListViewItem();
}
connection.Close();
```

El error se debe a que estás usando la variable `lvi` sin haberla limpiado de los datos anteriores.